# Pandas dataframe row extraction is changing dimensions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a **[2 rows x 51 columns]** dataframe read into a variable called "**csv**".
I want to create 2 new csv's from this, row based.
The first csv becomes **csv_row1** which will be **[1 row x 51 columns]**
The second csv becomes **csv_row2** which will be another **[1 row x 51 columns].**

I wrote just one line of code:

```
firstrow = csv.loc[0]
firstrowindex = len(firstrow.index)
print(firstrowindex)

#output 51
```

So, while I was expecting to view a **[1 row x 51 columns]** dataframe, I instead saw a **[51 rows x 2 columns]**

How can I do this differently? How can I extract a whole row of data and create a separate DataFrame for just that 1 row? And do this for each row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get row as a DataFrame you need to use:

```
csv_row1 = csv.loc[[0]]
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!